# My funds are stuck in a reserved state. How do I get them out?

Tags: yagna

I tried running a task on Golem via the Python API Yapapi, but it says I don't have enough funds for the allocation. When I then checked the `yagna payment status --driver zksync`, it says I have a lot of funds in the reserved state.

How do I get them out?

```
Status for account: [redacted]

┌────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────┬─────────────┬────────────┬────────────────────────────────┐
│  platform          │  total amount                 │  reserved                     │  amount     │  incoming  │  outgoing                      │
├────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────┼─────────────┼────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│  driver: zksync    │  111.271646252988321632 GLM   │  106.310490959782071751 GLM   │  accepted   │  0 GLM     │  305.416973117029318531 GLM  │
│  network: mainnet  │                               │                               │  confirmed  │  0 GLM     │  14.533081348947285750 GLM  │
│  token: GLM        │                               │                               │  requested  │  0 GLM     │  853.498111482561896347 GLM │
└────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────┴─────────────┴────────────┴────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Hi! You are going to be much more specific than this. What programming language are you using? What does your code look like? What have you tried so far? Where does the above come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Golem doesn't have any built in functionality at this current stage (v0.8.0) to automatically empty the reserved state. So what you can do is use this bash script to contact the local API to clear the reserved funds.

```
#!/bin/bash

appkey="$(yagna app-key list --json | jq -r .values[0][1])"
auth=("--header" "authorization: Bearer ${appkey}")
api_url="http://127.0.0.1:7465/payment-api/v1"

allocation_ids="$(curl "${auth[@]}" "${api_url}/allocations" | jq -r '.[]["allocationId"]')"
for allocation_id in ${allocation_ids}; do
    curl "${auth[@]}" -X DELETE "${api_url}/allocations/${allocation_id}"
done
```